# Doctrine @UniqueEntity with ManyToOne entity's one field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There is an **is_deleted** column available in **user** table.
While a user is deleted then record not deleted just is_deleted is set to 1.
Then i create new user with same phone number. it's display unique validation error.

I want to skip is_deleted record in validation.

**My UserProfiles Entity**

```
<?php

/**
 * UserProfiles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_profiles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class UserProfiles
 {

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $phoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ApiBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="userProfile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $user;
```

**Validation constraint yml.**

```
ApiBundle\Entity\UserProfiles:
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
        fields: [phoneNumber]
        errorPath: phone_number
        message: "Phone number is already exists."
```

I want to add user.is_deleted in fields:[phoneNumber, user.is_deleted]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure `UniqueEntity` constraint could solve your issue here because `is_deleted` is on a different entity. Most probably you'll need to use [`Expression`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) or [`Callback`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraints so you can achieve more complex dynamic validation and get `User` fields from `UserProfiles` entity.